# python pandas find first day and year of timeseries.weekofyear

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a datetime index on my dataframe and am able to find the week and the year respectively through `dataframe.weekofyear` and `dataframe.year`.

I would like to find the first day of what the "weekofyear" is considered so I can ultimately bin the groups by strings of "MONTH, DAY, YEAR". ('Jan 1, 2015', 'Jan 8, 2015', 'Jan 15, 2015', etc.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Won't the first day just be `np.arange(1,366,7)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reverse_df['week_str'] = pd.to_datetime((np.arange(1,366,7)[reverse_df['week']]).astype(str) + reverse_df['year'].astype(str), format="%j%Y")
```

Thanks EdChum, that was exactly what I needed.